# Detect key event (Enter) with JQuery in Javascript (on Linux platform)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Update:**

I finally figured out that "keypress" has a better compatibility than "keydown" or "keyup" on Linux platform. I just changed "keyup"/"keydown" to "keypress", so all went well.

I don't know what the reason is but it is solution for me. Thanks all who had responsed my question.

--

I have some codes that needs to detect key press event (I have to know when the user press Enter) with JQuery and here are the codes in Javascript:

```
j.input.bind("keyup", function (l) {
    if (document.selection) {
        g._ieCacheSelection = document.selection.createRange()
    }
}).bind("keydown", function(l) {
    //console.log(l.keyCode);
    if (l.keyCode == 13) {
        if(l.ctrlKey) {
            g.insertCursorPos("\n");
            return true;
        } else {
            var k = d(this),
            n = k.val();
            if(k.attr('intervalTime')) {
                    //alert('can not send');
                    k.css('color','red').val('Dont send too many messages').attr('disabled','disabled').css('color','red');
                    setTimeout(function(){k.css('color','').val(n).attr('disabled','').focus()},1000);
                    return
            }
    if(g_debug_num[parseInt(h.buddyInfo.id)]==undefined) {
            g_debug_num[parseInt(h.buddyInfo.id)]=1;
    }
        if (d.trim(n)) {
            var m = {
                to: h.buddyInfo.id,
                from: h.myInfo.id,
                //stype: "msg",
                body: (g_debug_num[parseInt(h.buddyInfo.id)]++)+" : "+n,
                timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()
            };
            //g.addHistory(m);
            k.val("");
            g.trigger("sendMessage", m);
            l.preventDefault();
            g.sendStatuses("");
            k.attr('intervalTime',100);
            setTimeout(function(){k.removeAttr('intervalTime')},1000);
            return
        }
        return
    }
}
```

It works fine on Windows but on Linux, it fails to catch the Enter event sometimes. Can someone help?

**Updated:**

It seems good if I only use English to talk. But I have to use some input method to input Chinese. If it is the problem? (JQuery can not detect Enter if I use Chinese input method? )

Comment: and Linux has nothing to do with it mate.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" >
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="TestTextBox" type="text" />
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
       var  testTextBox = $('#TestTextBox');
        var code =null;
        testTextBox.keypress(function(e)
        {
            code= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) alert('Enter key was pressed.');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The if block should include `e.preventDefault();` unless you want to disable all typing in the text box.

Answer (score 12):

Use `if (l.keyCode == 10 || l.keyCode == 13)` instead of `if (l.keyCode == 13)`...

Under Windows, a new line consists of a `Carriage Return` (13) followed by a `Line Feed` (10).

Under *nix, a new line consists of a `Line Feed` (10) only.

Under Mac, a new line consists of a `Carriage Return` (13) only.

Comment: I added "l.keyCode=10" but I still encountered the problem. And I use "console.log(l.keyCode)" to see what keyCode are, it seems there is only "13" when I press Enter (On linux)

Answer (score 0):

This ***could*** be a browser specific issue. Different browsers handle the keycode differently. It's good to normalize this prior to inspection:

```
var code = ev.keyCode || ev.charCode || 0;
```

It's important to note that webkit browsers have a slightly different key mapping than the rest:

```
var webkitKeymap = {
            63232: 38, // up
            63233: 40, // down
            63234: 37, // left
            63235: 39, // right
            63276: 33, // page up
            63277: 34, // page down
            25: 9      // SHIFT-TAB (Safari provides a different key code in
                       // this case, even though the shiftKey modifier is set)
        };
```

This code can be found in YUI's event utility.